# Is it possible to edit datasource data in SpagoBI Server 5.2

Tags: spagobi

I have running SpagoBI Server with birt reports and Talend jobs.

Is it possible to edit data in data source (database) from SpagoBI Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately SpagoBI 5.x does not support editing data from a data source or dataset. Depending on the use case , there are other options for presenting an interface for create, update, and delete options on data.